# Downloading page content via https from Azure web app protected by IP-SSL

Tags: ssl, azure-web-app-service, tls1.2

We have a very basic C# code doing a download of a page content via https (no credentials required).

```
new WebClient().DownloadString(new Uri(url));
```

We are hosting this code on two Azure web apps : one web app with no IP-SSL and another one with IP-SSL. It was working fine until a few weeks ago.

Now, it is still working fine on the first web site (no IP SSL) but is failing on the second one with the error :

"Message":"Unable to connect to the remote server","Data":null,"InnerException":{"NativeErrorCode":10060,"ClassName":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","Message":"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

At first, we thought there could be an issue with TLS (with the changes on security) or with the certificate of the remote site so we added the lines :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

but still it does not work...

Any ideas / ways of debugging ?

Comment: What is "IP-SSL"? TLS is TCP + crypto handshake and operations over IP.

Answer (score 0):

For the record : we changed the app service plan from premium v2 to a classic s3 which basically modified the outbound IPs addresses and made it work. Don't see why the previous Ip addresses would have been blacklisted...